# Why Bluedroid test on Android does not enable BT?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-ndk

I want to use Bluetooth using NDK. I found example here https://github.com/manuelnaranjo/bluedroid-tests. So, I tried to launch this test from /system/bin/bdt and put command enable, but I saw only:
`>enable
ENABLE BT
HAL REQUEST SUCCESS`

But does not type:

`>ADAPTER STATE UPDATED : ON`
as it should be according to [README.txt](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_bluetooth_bluedroid/blob/cm-12.0/test/rfcommtest/README.txt)

Why I do not see, that adapter is on? Maybe there is some other way to use Bluetooth via NDK?

Comment: First of all, can you enable bluetooth using the normal setting menu?

Comment: @Nei Sure, I can turn on bluetooth using Settings GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use bdt alongwith the native Bluetooth app. The reason is this that generally Bluetooth chips are serial devices which is opened by Bluedroid through it vendor library. Now, Bluedroid is loaded to memory by native Bluetooth App. If you want to start bdt, which will be another process, opening the device file of the bluetooth chip will fail as it is already opened by native BLuetooth app and due to this non of the functionality of the test app bdt will work.

If you want to use bdt, kill the native app Bluetooth app and change the permission of its binary to 0666 such that it won't start again by itself. Now, try to run bdt. it will work.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. It is really work. I just removed Bluetooth.apk file and then bdt worked well.